# Installing ruby 1.9.1 on OS X with RVM, getting error I can't make sense of

Tags: macos, installation, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to update my ruby install on Leopard to at least 1.9.1.
I found a tutorial that tells me how to do it with RVM and I get as far as downloading, configuring and compiling the version I want, but during the compile I get errors.

When checking the make.error.log file this is the message I get:

```
[2010-11-07 13:43:44] make 
main.c: In function ‘objcdummyfunction’:
main.c:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘objc_msgSend’
main.c: At top level:
main.c:19: warning: ‘objcdummyfunction’ defined but not used
eval.c: In function ‘ruby_cleanup’:
eval.c:139: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ruby_init_stack’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
gc.c: In function ‘garbage_collect_with_gvl’:
gc.c:597: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
w: illegal option -- L
usage: w [hi] [user ...]
make: [libruby.1.9.1.dylib] Error 1 (ignored)
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1159: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1159: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1159: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

I have no idea what any of that means.  Help?

Comment: Ruby is available via [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), currently at version 1.9.2-p180. Homebrew makes sure you have all dependencies in compatible versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RVM docs have a page with a suggestion for readline issues: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/